# Виртуальный ip маршрутизатор на php

Tags: php, vpn, маршрутизатор

Идея безумна, но существует ли в природе виртуальный ip маршрутизатор, который можно развернуть на php хостинге? Нужно для маршрутизации управляющих каналов, и созданию vpn туннелей.

Comment: Что такое "маршрутизация управляющих каналов"?

Comment: @PavelMayorov управляющие каналы - это каналы через которые планируется устанавливать соединение с сервером(или другим устройством) для его удалённого администрирования. Т.е. подразумевается что эти каналы будут мало нагружены. Маршрутизация здесь используется в привычном её понимании.

Comment: В привычном понимании маршрутизацию выполняет драйвер ядра. В отрыве от других технологий, виртуальный маршрутизатор нельзя написать ни на одном языке программирования потому что маршрутизатор в системе может быть всего один и он уже есть.

Comment: @PavelMayorov существуют же эмуляторы, вот я и подумал что и такое возможно. Сугубо теоретически конечно.